# Missing the second flight booked by ourselves due the delay in the first?

Tags: transit, connecting-flights, delays

I want to book a flight from city A to B from Qatar Airways ( A-Doha-B) which takes at least 10 hours and book another flight from city B to C from Qatar Airways again ( B-Doha-C) one day after I arrive in city B. I want to book these two flight by self, that is, I have two separate tickets and booking references. So, If I miss the second flight due to a delay in the first flight, what can I do? Since two flights are from Qatari, does it compensate for the second flight?

Best

Comment: why do you actively want separate booking references? It seems you know there will be no compensation in that case, yet you want somehow that there could be anyway?

Comment: @KateGregory I want to know is there any responsibility for delays occurred by airways?

Comment: I know that's your question. My comment was why are you doing this? If both tickets are from the same airline you could do them all as one itinerary, do you have a reason not to?

Comment: Apart from doing a job in city B, also the price of booking these 2 flights is 60 percent of one flight ( A->C)! 1600$ ( A->B->C) to 2400$(A->C)!

Comment: What if you book A->B->C as a multi-city option with the airlines?

Comment: surely this is a many-times dupe ?

Comment: I actually did this once (because Travelocity or whoever wouldn't let me book it; they were *not* the same airline) and found out why.  At airport 'B', I had to leave the first terminal, hike to another terminal (there was no transportation between them), and be re-screened through security.  If I had checked a bag, I would've had to wait for it at the baggage claim, and re-check it.

Comment: @hojusaram I try to decrease the cost of the ticket! and I don't know it would be done by this

Comment: It might be higher than 1600 but lower than 2400 and delays etc would be covered by the airlines. You can also look at kiwi.com https://www.kiwi.com/en/help/insurance-and-the-kiwi-com-guarantee-135/article/what-is-the-kiwi-com-guarantee-28

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, if they are booked separately, it is your sole responsibility to be there in time for the check-in and boarding deadlines of the second flight. If you miss it, you'll either have to change the booking (**before** the check-in deadline, usually, though it may depend on the fare, and possibly with penalties/fees and a fare difference), or book and pay for a new ticket. Remember that in some cases, missing the first flight on a return ticket may cancel the whole return trip. Also remember that if the next available flight is the following day, you'll have to pay for your hotel, meals, transportation, etc.

Whether you get to the airport on foot, by public transport, in your car or via another flight does not matter, and the fact that it's the same airline does not matter either.

The airline **may** take the situation into account, but that's purely goodwill on their part, they have absolutely no legal or contractual obligation to do so.

You **may** however be covered by your travel insurance (including those sold by airlines and booking sites, or those bundled with some credit cards). This will depend on the exact terms of your travel insurance (and if you have one and it covers this flight, of course).

Options for you include:

- Booking the whole trip as one ticket (multi-city or with a stop-over, in your case)
- Booking the second flight with a flexible fare that allows free or cheap changes (but you're still on the hook for hotels etc. if you have to stay overnight)
- Adding more buffer (overnight is usually more than enough for short-haul flights or flights on busy routes, but may be an issue with infrequent long-haul flights, which are probably a lot more frequent these days).
- Having good travel insurance (double-check the terms and exclusions).

Good travel insurance seems like a must anyway these days, given all the risks surrounding travel (cancellations, border closures, etc.).

Comment: Apart from doing a job in city B, also the price of booking these 2 flights is 60 percent of one flight ( A->C)!
I need to check the fare and insurance.

Comment: You may also experience that the first flight is cancelled and the second is going but you are unable to make it as you can not get to the airport it starts from. The airline is taking that risk for money, you can take that risk but you better insure it.

Comment: @Willeke I do not think so! since, every flight in QatarAirways, it stops in Doha ( A->Doha->B, B->Doha->C is 1600 and A->Doha->C is 2400)

Comment: Not related to financial obligations, but be also aware that a potential right to transit without a visa or just a transit visa as opposed to having a proper visitor's visa may require that you have a through ticket and not two separate bookings.

Comment: @mahdi_12167: "the price of booking these 2 flights is 60 percent of one flight" – Yes. One reason for that may be that the airline thinks the risk of missing the second flight is high, and so they include the cost associated with that risk (having to pay for your hotel, paying you compensation for the delay, rebooking you onto a potentially more expensive flight, providing you with laundry in case your luggage makes it to the second flight but you don't, etc.) in the price of the ticket. If you book the tickets separate, then it is *you* who is responsible for that cost.

Comment: @mahdi_1267 Can you clarify what the the cities are, and whether you actually need to be in B for other reasons, or if the only thing that matters for you is going from A to C? Also are booking one way or return?

Comment: @mahdi_12167, flights from Doha might go but flights from A to Doha may not go at all, for several reasons. One of them may be that the COVID 19 numbers go up or that the government of the country does not want anybody coming in and stops all planes coming into the country/area.

Comment: Be aware that making separate bookings may allow you to inadvertently [violate cabotage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/152688/104571), causing you to be temporarily stranded.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo For entering country A, I don't need to get a visa and I should do a one-day job.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand it. But for every flight, it stops in Doha! When I travel to city B, I need to change the plan in Doha. And when I travel from B to C, again I change the plan in Doha! "As the crow flies" does not apply here! (A->Doha->C) > (A->Doha->B) + (B->Doha->C)

Comment: @jcaron I want to move from Mashhad(MHD, Iran) as A to Montreal (YUL, Canada) as C. The most important reason is arriving in Montreal but apart from doing one thing in Istanbul(SAW, Turkey), the price is more affordable to get two separate bookings!