# Is it mandatory to be in Turkey for 14 days for non Turkish residents, If we want to flight from Turkey to abroad?

Tags: turkey

I want to travel to Istanbul from Iran and the next day I'll fly to Canada from Istanbul (Two flights would be done by Qatar Airways). Can I do that?
Is it mandatory to be in Turkey for 14 days for non-Turkish residents, If we want to flight from Turkey to abroad?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking if a 14 day quarantine exists for persons in transit? Would you have to leave the airport? Time between flights?

Comment: @MarkJohnson I want this: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161043/missing-the-second-flight-booked-by-ourselves-due-the-delay-in-the-first

Comment: It is still not clear whst you want. Are you asking if each visitor is required to stay a minimum of 14 days in Turkey? The answer to that is no.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I mean I ask if each visitor who wants to travel to another country differs from the country which he or she came is required to stay a minimum of 14 days in Turkey?

Comment: I have never heard of such a requirement from any country for a short term visit. For transit there are time restrictions where a transit visa has been issued.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it mandatory to be in Turkey for 14 days for non Turkish residents, If we want to flight from Turkey to abroad?

No (there's currently no mandatory quarantine when entering Turkey).

> the next day I'll fly to Canada from Istanbul

See [the IATA travel center](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm) for Canada travel restrictions.  (Most people currently can't enter)

Comment: I think the OP is asking also about entry to Canada from Turkey? The route appears to be Iran > Turkey > Canada

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Apart from the Covid-19 situation, one said to me if you see the flights from Istanbul to many places is cheaper since they forced you to be at least 14 days in the current year.

Comment: @mahdi_12167 incorrect

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt How can I become sure? I want to book a flight asap.